# OneSignal register a new android device by php

Tags: php, android, push-notification, notifications, onesignal

I am trying to register the android device with php,but from what i read in the documentation i have to get identifier

> (Push notification identifier from Google or Apple. For Apple push
>   identifiers, you must strip all non alphanumeric characters. Example:
>   ce777617da7f548fe7a9ab6febb56).

My question is, where to get the identifier on android ?

My plan was : run app ,android will get this identifier -> the user completes the login form-> data logging and identifier are POST to php script-> if the login succeeds script register android device in OneSignal.

Link for [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#add-a-device).

Answer (score -1):

You can query the OneSignal Android SDK for the registration identifier via [OneSignal.idsAvailable](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--idsavailable-):

```
OneSignal.idsAvailable(new IdsAvailableHandler() {
  @Override
  public void idsAvailable(String userId, String registrationId) {
    Log.d("debug", "User:" + userId);
    if (registrationId != null)
      Log.d("debug", "registrationId:" + registrationId);
  }
});
```